# Imageview is not dropping at drop event

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, ontouchlistener

I'm trying the `onDrag` event to move the `ImageView`. My `ImageView` is moving very well but my problem is that the `ImageView` is not getting Visible at last position of `DROP` event.
Following is my code...Where am I making mistake?

```
package com.example.dragndropdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipDescription;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
   ImageView ima;
   private static final String IMAGEVIEW_TAG = "Android Logo";
   String msg;

   private android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      ima = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_logo);
      // Sets the tag
      ima.setTag(IMAGEVIEW_TAG);

      ima.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence)v.getTag());

                    String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};
                    ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);
                    // Instantiates the drag shadow builder.
                    DragShadow dragShadow=new DragShadow(v);

                    // Starts the drag
                    v.startDrag(dragData    // the data to be dragged
                            , dragShadow    // the drag shadow builder
                            , v             // no need to use local data
                            , 0             // flags (not currently used, set to 0)
                            );
                    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
         }
      });

      // Create and set the drag event listener for the View
      ima.setOnDragListener( new OnDragListener(){
         @Override
         public boolean onDrag(View v,  DragEvent event){
             int dragEvent=event.getAction();
         switch(event.getAction())                   
         {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
               Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
               // Do nothing
               break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
               Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
               break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :
               Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
               break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
               Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
               break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :
               Log.d(msg, "Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
               // Do nothing
               break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
               Log.d(msg, "ACTION_DROP event");
               ImageView imgvw=(ImageView)event.getLocalState();
               imgvw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               break;

            default: break;
            }
            return true;
         }
      });           
   }

   private class DragShadow extends View.DragShadowBuilder
   {

    public DragShadow(View view) {
        super(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDrawShadow(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint) {
        View v= getView();

        int height=v.getHeight();
        int width=v.getWidth();

        shadowSize.set(width, height);
        shadowTouchPoint.set((int)width/2,(int)height/2);
    }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with the same problem for a few hours now. But I found a solution inside the ApiDemos. You can look inside the package `com.example.android.apis.view` and you will see `DragAndDropDemo.java`

Inside, you will notice that the draggable objects are instances of `DraggableDot`, which are also the drop points. And then looking inside `DraggableDot`, it is simply a subclass of `View` that implements `onDragEvent`.

In the end, I created a subclass of `View` and plugged the `onDragEvent` method. I used this subclass as my drop points and, surprisingly, my `DragListener` started registering the other `DragEvent` actions, especially the `ACTION_DROP`.

Answer (score -1):

**Change:**

```
ImageView imgvw=(ImageView)event.getLocalState();

imgvw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

**for:**

```
v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```